# Problem running loops in shell script via ansible

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, sh

I'm having problems when I try to run a .sh on servers via Ansible, when running the playbook, all instructions that are executed other than the loop are executed, but the loop commands are skipped

When I run the shell script manually it performs the loop and all the commands correctly

Here is the excerpt from my shell script code where the loop is:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
# Allow traffic IPs
for IP in `cat rangeip.txt`; of
     sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 37183 -s $IP -j ACCEPT
done
...
```

Now the code for my Ansible Playbook task to run the .sh:

```
   - name: exec .sh
     shell: /scripts/bloq.sh
```

I'm running playbook as root

Has anyone experienced something similar or know anything about this problem?

I expected it to execute all instructions from my shell script

Comment: Give a full path to the file `rangeip.txt` or use `chdir` to change to the folder where the file is located. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html#parameter-chdir

Comment: I hate to ask - but why aren't you using the ansible [iptables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/iptables_module.html) module? With you approach to run a shell-script you lose idempotency ...

Comment: Then I used the iptable module and it worked, but this question arose about running shell scripts via ansible... I have many shell scripts but it is unfeasible to manage so many servers without ansible

In some cases, moving the entire shell structure to Ansible would take days, as some update some applications

Comment: `for var in \`cat ...\`` is [bad practice](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award) for several reasons, like [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). You might also consider [Moving the loop into Ansible itself](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html). In the very least, make sure `rangeip.txt` is where `/scripts/bloq.sh` is executing, preferably specified with a full path.

Comment: thanks for the article! I read and understood the best practice
In my next playbooks / shell scripts, I will follow the tips you gave me

Answer (score -1):

It appears there is a syntax error in your script. The issue is in the for loop. You have a typo in the loop syntax, and the **of** keyword is not valid (should be **do**). Here's the corrected script:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
# Allow traffic IPs
for IP in `cat <absolute path of the file>/rangeip.txt`; do
     sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 37183 -s $IP -j ACCEPT
done
...
```